# Avoid repeating javascript for each element

Tags: javascript, performance, dialog, modal-dialog, polyfills

I'm using the Google [dialog-polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill) for modals on my site.  I need to have multiple modals on a page that can be launched independently.  Right now, the only method that I can get to work is to repeat all of the javascript, which seems completely inefficient:

```
<dialog id="dialog" name="modal">
    <p>This is the login modal dialog.</p>
    <input type="text"></input>
    <p><button id="close-dialog">Close dialog</button></p>
</dialog>
<p><button id="open-dialog">Open login dialog</button></p>

<dialog id="dialog2" name="modal">
    <p>This is the registration modal dialog.</p>
    <input type="text"></input>
    <p><button id="close-dialog2">Close dialog</button></p>
</dialog>
<p><button id="open-dialog2">Open registration dialog</button></p>

<script>
    var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
    var dialog2 = document.getElementById('dialog2');
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog2);

    document.getElementById('open-dialog').addEventListener('click', function () {
        dialog.showModal();     });
    document.getElementById('close-dialog').addEventListener('click', function () {
        dialog.close();     });

    document.getElementById('open-dialog2').addEventListener('click', function () {
        dialog2.showModal();     });
    document.getElementById('close-dialog2').addEventListener('click', function () {
        dialog2.close();     });

    dialog.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var rect = dialog.getBoundingClientRect();
        var isInDialog = (rect.top <= event.clientY && event.clientY <= rect.top + rect.height && rect.left <= event.clientX && event.clientX <= rect.left + rect.width);
        if (!isInDialog) {
            dialog.close();
        }
    });

    dialog2.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var rect = dialog2.getBoundingClientRect();
        var isInDialog = (rect.top <= event.clientY && event.clientY <= rect.top + rect.height && rect.left <= event.clientX && event.clientX <= rect.left + rect.width);
        if (!isInDialog) {
            dialog2.close();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've played around with this and adding `name` attributes to no avail:

```
    var names = document.getElementsByName("modal");
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i].onchange = function () {
            document.getElementById('open-dialog').addEventListener('click', function () {
                dialog.showModal();
            });
            document.getElementById('close-dialog').addEventListener('click', function () {
                dialog.close();
            });
        }
    }
```

I don't see how classes would solve this.  Is there a way to condense the code so that I won't need to repeat it for each and every modal dialog?

Comment: I wonder if a foreach would be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/178f81qc/2/

Is this what you mean?

HTML

```
<div class="dialog-container">
    <dialog>This is dialog one <button class="close">close</button></dialog>

    <button class="open">open dialog one</button>
</div>

<br>

<div class="dialog-container">
    <dialog>This is dialog two <button class="close">close</button></dialog>

    <button class="open">open dialog two</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var dialogContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.dialog-container'), i;
for (i=0; i<dialogContainers.length; i++) {

    var dialog = dialogContainers[i].querySelector('dialog'), // the <dialog> element
        btnOpen = dialogContainers[i].querySelector('.open'),  // the open button
        btnClose = dialogContainers[i].querySelector('.close'); // the close button

    // for old browsers
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialogContainers[i]);

    btnOpen.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.showModal();
    }.bind(dialog));

    // because you bind 'dialog' to the function, 'this' will be the dialog.
    // (if you don't use bind, 'this' will be btnOpen instead)

    btnClose.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.close();
    }.bind(dialog));
}
```

Comment: I see what you're doing, but that is not compatible with the dialog polyfill.  In fact, your code doesn't even use the dialog element.  The html elements that I have cannot be changed; attributes can be, but not the elements.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. But `dialog` for you is the element too right? (`var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');`) and you have a handler that does dialog.something(); so you should be able to use 'this' instead of that reference (dialog, dialog2, etc.).

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do now, sorry didn't realize it before. I've updated my answer and edited your fiddle.

Comment: That works.  Thanks.  Your javascript is a little heavier than my solution; is there any performance benefit to using your over mine?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I added a class to to the dialogs so that I could get all of them; I probably could have just selected by tag name, but that would lock me into only modal dialogs.  Then I modified my script thus:

```
<script>
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {

        var dialogid = el.id;
        var dialog = document.getElementById(dialogid);
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);

        document.getElementById('open-'+dialogid).addEventListener('click', function () {
            dialog.showModal();
        });
        document.getElementById('close-'+dialogid).addEventListener('click', function () {
            dialog.close();
        });
        dialog.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            var rect = dialog.getBoundingClientRect();
            var isInDialog = (rect.top <= event.clientY && event.clientY <= rect.top + rect.height && rect.left <= event.clientX && event.clientX <= rect.left + rect.width);
            if (!isInDialog) {
                dialog.close();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I really don't like answering my own questions, but this worked.  If anyone can come up with a more efficient method, I'll gladly give him credit.